# A question on Kernel.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $K(x,y)$ is a symmetric kernel and $K(x,.), K(.,y)$ are in $L^1(\Omega)$. Let $\phi\in L^{2}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ everywhere is a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can $\int K(x,y)\phi(y)dy$ belong to $L^2$?. In other words can an inequality of the type $||\int K(x,y)\phi(y)dy||_{2}\leq||K||_{L^1{\Omega\times\Omega}}||\phi||_{2}$ exist?.

Comment: Raff...Thanks for pointing it out...Assume that $K(.,.)\in L^1_{\Omega\times\Omega}$ with $K$ having a singularity at $x=y$. Does this help me to conclude an inequality of the above mentioned type?.

Comment: What if $K$ is the derivative of a Green's function?.

Comment: Anyone out there to answer me please?.

Comment: Both the questions have been posted by me. I was trying to get an answer from the view point of functional analyst and an applied analyst.